# Calculate customer activity in specific periods (example : 7 days)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, churn

I have managed to calculate if a customer is active in a monthly period, and not active in the next period (churn) using CTEs. This has proven to be very straight forward so far. My code snippet used to do so (for others looking around on how to do this) is the following. My `dwh.marts.fact_customer_kpi` table has records representing that a customer has been `active`, and that means that he/she has spent some money using services.

```
with monthly_usage as (
  select
    userid as who_identifier,
    datediff(month, '1970-01-01', date) as time_period,
    date_part(mon,date) as month,
    date_part(yr,date) as year,
    CAST(
      CAST(date_part(yr,date) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(date_part(mon,date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
   AS DATETIME)as day
  from dwh.marts.fact_customer_kpi as k
          inner join dwh.marts.dim_user as u on u.user_id = k.userid
  where 
  kpi = 'ACTIVE' and (datediff(month, CURRENT_DATE, registration_date)*-1) > 1 group by 1,2,3,4,5 order by 1,2,3,4,5)
,

lag_lead as (
  select who_identifier,
  time_period,
  year,
  month,
  day,
    lag(time_period,1) over (partition by who_identifier order by who_identifier, time_period),
    lead(time_period,1) over (partition by who_identifier order by who_identifier, time_period)
  from monthly_usage)

,

lag_lead_with_diffs as (
  select who_identifier,
    year,
    month,
    day,
    time_period,
    lag,
    lead,
    time_period-lag lag_size,
    lead-time_period lead_size
  from lag_lead)
,

calculated as (
select time_period,
  year,
  month,
  day,
  case when lag is null then 'NEW ACTIVE'
     when lag_size = 1 then 'ACTIVE'
     when lag_size > 1 then 'REACTIVATED'
  end as this_month_value,
  case when (lead_size > 1 OR lead_size IS NULL) then 'CHURN'
     else NULL
  end as next_month_churn,
  who_identifier,
  count(who_identifier) as countIdentifier
   from lag_lead_with_diffs group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

select time_period,
    day,
  this_month_value,
  who_identifier,
  next_month_churn,
  sum(countIdentifier) as countIdentifier
  from calculated  group by 1,2,3,4,5
union
  select time_period+1,
  dateadd(month,1,day),
  'CHURN',
  who_identifier,
  next_month_churn,
  countIdentifier
  from calculated where next_month_churn is not null
order by 1;
```

However, now I am wondering if there is an efficient way in Redshift to calculate periods based on specific dates. Say for example, calculate the same above, however instead of monthly, based on 7 day periods from when the customer registered.

The changes required in my query would be required in `monthly_usage`. I have tried using `- interval '7 days'` but without success so far, or I am missing something.

Can anyone point me to what I am missing (ideally with an example), or what changes would be required?

I am using Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing [date_trunc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) function? Because it feels like it.

You can replace this:

```
    CAST(
      CAST(date_part(yr,date) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(date_part(mon,date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
   AS DATETIME)as day
```

You can do this:

```
date_trunc('month', date)
```

Then I guess parametrize this in some nice language, and easily swap out for other [dateparts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html).
I would probably also swap out `datediff(month, '1970-01-01', date)` for `EXTRACT`

Comment: The example above calculates successfully with monthly periods. What I would like to do is, instead of calculate the above by monthly periods, do the same except for date range periods, such as 7 days. I could not get around what functions to use this - to use CTEs. So instead of a CTE monthly_usage, I would have another CTE 7day_usage.

Comment: Yes, you would need an additional cte, like so:
`with weekly_usage as (
  select
    userid as who_identifier,
    datediff(month, '1970-01-01', date) as time_period,
    date_part(mon,date) as month,
    date_part(yr,date) as year,
  date_trunc('week', date) as day
  from dwh.marts.fact_customer_kpi as k
          inner join dwh.marts.dim_user as u on u.user_id = k.userid
  where 
  kpi = 'ACTIVE' and (datediff(month, CURRENT_DATE, registration_date)*-1) > 1 group by 1,2,3,4,5 order by 1,2,3,4,5)
`

Comment: And if it where to be periods of for example 3 days (not weekly)? Any functions that help with those intervals?

Comment: Without recursive common table expressions - no.

Comment: How would I be able to use a CTE if I wanted to have periods such as 3 days?

Comment: *Recursive* CTE, Redshift currently doesn't have those.